# Intense FOUC when using Next.js 8 and styled-jsx

Tags: reactjs, styled-components, next.js, css-in-js

I have recently upgraded to Next.js `8.0.3` from `6.1.1` and I am now encountering a very intense flash of un-styled content (FOUC) for my header content which is using `styled-jsx`. It loaded just fine before updating Next.js.

The header code that is flashing is a custom built npm module that uses `styled-jsx` (but not `next`) and is being imported and placed into a layout page that is rendered with every `next` page.

This was the implementation in the `_document.js` file before updating `next` and it was working:

```
import Document, { Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document'
import { ServerStyleSheet, injectGlobal } from 'styled-components'
import styledNormalize from 'styled-normalize'
import flush from 'styled-jsx/server'
injectGlobal`
  ${styledNormalize}
`
export default class MyDocument extends Document {
  static getInitialProps({ renderPage }) {
    const sheet = new ServerStyleSheet()
    const page = renderPage(App => props =>
      sheet.collectStyles(<App {...props} />)
    )
    const styleTags = sheet.getStyleElement()
    const styles = flush()
    return { ...page, styleTags, styles }
  }
  render() {
    return (
       <html>
        <Head>
          {this.props.styleTags}
        </Head>
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </html>
    )
  }
}
```

Based on the [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/#custom-document) I have also tried this (where I wait for the initial props):

```
import Document, { Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document'
import { ServerStyleSheet, injectGlobal } from 'styled-components'
import styledNormalize from 'styled-normalize'
import flush from 'styled-jsx/server'
injectGlobal`
  ${styledNormalize}
`
export default class MyDocument extends Document {
  static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
    const sheet = new ServerStyleSheet()
    const page = ctx.renderPage(App => props =>
      sheet.collectStyles(<App {...props} />)
    )
    const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx)
    const styleTags = sheet.getStyleElement()
    const styles = flush()
    return { ...initialProps, ...page, styles, styleTags }
  }
  render() {
    return (
       <html>
        <Head>
          {this.props.styleTags}
        </Head>
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </html>
    )
  }
}
```

The flash might be a result of where I am implementing the module but not sure.

It seems like the code coming in from the module is not being properly bundled with the rest of the pages and thus giving the page flash. Any thoughts or feedback would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up fixing the issue by refactoring the custom npm module to not use styled-jsx but instead use styled-components. Not really a fix but more of a work around